# Sophomore's Dream : integral not defined in x=0

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, power-series

Sophomore's dream is the identity that states

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 x^x dx = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^{-n}
\end{equation}

The proof is found  using the series expansion for $e^{-x\log(x)}$ and switching the integral and the sum. But I have a problem : I don't understand why I can replace $x^x$ in the integral by the series expansion of $e^{-x\log(x)}$ because the series is not defined in $x=0$.

In understand that in the integral, we can extend the function $x^x$ in $x=0$ because the limit is finite but then the extended function doesn't admit a series expansion for $x=0$.

What is the easiest way to solve this issue ?

Thank you !

Comment: The set $\{0\}$ is null.

Comment: $0^0\equiv 1$ see that $x^x\to 1$ as $x\to0$

Comment: I know that the limit is finite (and so that the integral is well defined) but I don't know why I can replace $x^x$ by its series expansion, because they are not equal for $x=0$.

Comment: $$\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x\ln x=0$$
BTW: I guess the proof uses the expansion of $e^{+x\ln x}$

Comment: The point is, the series and the integrated function having the same form is just a coincidence. This is why this integral is famous. You are looking too deep

Comment: @Divingo, It's an improper integral. More precisely written, the integral is actually $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\limits_\epsilon^1 x^x\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @GuyFsone $0^0$ is not defined in the real numbers. $\lim_{x\to 0+} 0^x = 0$ so it depends on how you approach the limit.

Comment: The value at $x=0$ does not matter. $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,dx = \int_{(0,1)}f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, but the easiest theorems for switching the integral and the sum are available because we work on a compact. If I work on $(0,1)$, I can't use them, can I ?

Comment: @Divingo: I am just saying there is no issue at all. You may redefine the values of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ in any way you like, and the integral (in the Riemann or Lebesgue sense), if existing, is still the same. If $f(x)$ is a continuous and bounded function on $(0,1)$, you may simply re-define (if needed) $f(0)$ as $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ and $f(1)$ as $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)$. Now you have a continuous function on a compact set.

Comment: Why are we concerned about definition of the function at a single specific point? The existence / value of a Riemann integral does not depend on the value of a function at a finite number of points. The function can be defined in any manner whatsoever at $x=0$.

Comment: Also the theory of Riemann integral deals with bounded function on closed (bounded) intervals and can be extended to unbounded functions / intervals via improper Riemann integrals. Here none of that is required as the function as well as interval is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I(k,n)=\int\limits_0^1x^k\ln^nxdx.$$
Thus, $$I(k,n)=\int\limits_0^1x^k\ln^nxdx=\frac{x^{k+1}\ln^nx}{k+1}\big|_0^1-\frac{n}{k+1}\int\limits_0^1x^k\ln^{n-1}xdx=-\frac{nI(k,n-1)}{k+1}.$$
Thus, 
$$I(k,n)\prod_{i=2}^{n}I(k,i-1)=I(k,n)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}I(k,i)=\prod_{i=1}^nI(k,i)=$$
$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(-\frac{i}{k+1}I(k,i-1)\right)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(k+1)^n}\prod_{i=2}^{n}I(k,i-1)I(k,0)=$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(k+1)^n}\prod_{i=2}^{n}I(k,i-1)\int\limits_0^1x^kdx=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\prod_{i=2}^{n}I(k,i-1),$$
which gives
$$I(k,n)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(k+1)^{n+1}},$$ 
$$I(k,k)=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$$ and
$$\int\limits_{0}^1x^xdx=\int\limits_0^1e^{x\ln{x}}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\int\limits_0^1\frac{x^k\ln^kx}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int\limits_0^1x^k\ln^kxdx=$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^n}.$$
Done!

Comment: This is old but an excellent answer that I enjoyed reading - shame it was never accepted

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^x & 0 < x \leq 1, \\
1 & x = 0. \end{cases},
g(x) = \begin{cases} x \ln x & 0 < x \leq 1, \\
0 & x = 0. \end{cases} $$

Both $f,g$ are continuous on $[0,1]$ and we have $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. The image of $g$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so it lies in some interval $[-N,N]$. The power series of $e^x$ converges uniformly on any closed interval so if we plug $g$ into the power series of $e^x$ (obtaining a function series, not a power series!), we still have an identity and uniform convergence. Namely,

$$ f(x) = e^{g(x)} = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} \frac{g(x)^n}{n!} $$

where the sum on the right hand side converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $e^{g(x)} = f(x)$.

Comment: As to how the integral $\int_0^1 x^x \, dx$ is defined at the first place (taking into account that the expression isn't defined at $x = 0$), there are two options: You can treat it as an improper integral and so by definition $\int_0^1 x^x \, dx = \lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}} \int_{\delta}^1 x^x \, dx$ and all the calculations should be done anyway on $[\delta,1]$ which doesn't have any problematic point. Alternatively, you can note that $x^x$ extends to the continuous function $f$ and then define $\int_0^1 x^x \, dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$. By the continuity of the integral of an integrable

Comment: function as a function of its (lower) limit, both definitions agree.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it really helps me ! If I work on $[\delta, 1]$, I will have to switch $\sum$ and $\lim\limits_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+}$ which over complicate things (but it could be done).